# Find $n$ for $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{(\cos x-1)(\cos x-e^{x})}{x^{n}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{(\cos{x}-1)(\cos{x}-e^{x})}{x^{n}} \right)$$ is a non-zero finite number for an integer $n$, then find the value of $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1-\cos{x} = \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4)$$

$$e^x-\cos{x} = x + O(x^2)$$

Clearly, $n=3$.